# Getting Error: data and salt arguments required when using bcryot and knex

Tags: node.js, express, server

I am trying to use bcrypt and knex to insert data from my request body into my server, defined by the "db" variable.

```
 app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
      const { email, name, password } = req.body;
      const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);
      db.transaction((trx) => {
        trx
          .insert({
            hash: hash,
            email: email,
          })
          .into("login")
          .returning("email")
          .then((loginEmail) => {
            return trx("users")
              .returning("*")
              .insert({
                email: loginEmail[0].email,
                name: name,
              })
              .then((user) => {
                res.json(user[0]);
              });
          })
          .then(trx.commit)
          .catch(trx.rollback);
      }).catch((err) => res.status(400).json("unable to register"));
    });
```

All answers are appreciated. I really need the help.

Comment: Where is the SQL this question is supposedly about?

Comment: Please [read how the bcrypt API works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#api).